# Selenium 4.16 Python: (no such element) and (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.130); For documentation on this error)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

- 

type here I am trying to use Selenium 4.16 on Py Charm, I run the below code and get the error message:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")

driver.find_element(By.NAME,"username").send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element(By.NAME,"password").send_keys("admin123")
```

---

```
C:\Code\PythonSelenium\PythonSelenium\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Code\PythonSelenium\PythonSelenium\selenium\FirstTestCase.py
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\PythonSelenium\PythonSelenium\selenium\FirstTestCase.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.NAME,"username").send_keys("Admin")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Code\PythonSelenium\PythonSelenium\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 742, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Code\PythonSelenium\PythonSelenium\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 348, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Code\PythonSelenium\PythonSelenium\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="username"]"}`
```

Answer (score 0):

**XPATH** is better approach than **ID**. I have tried with **XPATH** and it works for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# Wait for the username field to be present
username_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')))
username_field.send_keys("Admin")

password_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/input')
password_field.send_keys("admin123")
time.sleep(5)
# Assuming there's a login button with ID 'btnLogin'
login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[3]/button')
login_button.click()
time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: You are my Master ! Really appreciate, I was using Java Selenium on Intellij,  just begin to learn Python Selenium,  the difference is so big. Again, many many thanks for your time and patient. Thank you !

Comment: @user20234346 Its my pleasure.